# Android MediaCodec: decode, process each frame, then encode

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

The example DecodeEditEncodeTest.java in bigflake.com, demonstrates an example of simple editing (swap the color channels using OpenGL FRAGMENT_SHADER).

Here, I want to do some complicated image processing (such as adding something in it) of each frame.
In this way, does it mean I cannot use surface. Instead, I need to use buffer?
But from EncodeDecodeTest.java, it says:

```
(1)    Buffer-to-buffer. Buffers are software-generated YUV frames in ByteBuffer objects, and decoded to the same. This is the slowest (and least portable) approach, but it allows the application to examine and modify the YUV data.
(2)    Buffer-to-surface. Encoding is again done from software-generated YUV data in ByteBuffers, but this time decoding is done to a Surface. Output is checked with OpenGL ES, using glReadPixels().
(3)    Surface-to-surface. Frames are generated with OpenGL ES onto an input Surface, and decoded onto a Surface. This is the fastest approach, but may involve conversions between YUV and RGB.
```

If I use Buffer-to-buffer, from what the above says, it is the slowest and least portable. How slow would it be?

Or I use surface-to-surface, and read pixels out from the surface.

Which way is more feasible?
Any example available?

Comment: If you can do what you want with OpenGL ES, you should.  If you can't, `glReadPixels()` + edit + `glTexImage2d()` might be your best bet.  Another alternative is to use a 3rd-party library like ffmpeg and just do the whole thing in software.

Comment: @fadden, thanks. In your guessing, among the two methods: glReadPixels() + edit + glTexImage2d(), or using ffmpeg, which is better (faster)? I guess ffmpeg is faster, since it has no OpenGL surface rendering step. What about your opinion?

Comment: It's going to vary from system to system.  The performance of the GL commands depends on the GPU and drivers, and the performance of ffmpeg depends on the CPU.  The GLES rendering isn't a concern -- it should be very fast on nearly anything -- it's getting big bitmaps in and out of GLES that tends to hit slow paths.  If nothing else, working entirely in YUV with ffmpeg will avoid conversion steps.  I haven't worked with ffmpeg, though, so I don't have a sense for encoding quality and performance relative to the hardware codecs.

Comment: @fadden, thank you very much for your explanation. I have another question. If the video source is not from a file, but from the camera, and I want to do real time video processing, I think I need the camera gives me a raw data of each frame before I feed them into "edit + encoding". It seems examples from bigflake.com show one way to get camera frame raw data by using camera.preview. But I think it is slow (since it has been through some unnecessary process I guess, and also has low frame rate). Can we get the raw data of each frame directly from camera hardware?

Comment: Have you seen "Show + capture camera" in Grafika?  https://github.com/google/grafika (demo at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg).

Comment: @fadden, I just took a look at "Show+capture camera" in Grafika. The output video file shows it is 10 fps, no matter I choose normal or emboss filter. I think 10 fps is relatively low. I remember one post mentioned that it is due to camera preview function has a low fps. It might be better to directly use data from camera recorder? But it seems for now no api to use frame raw data directly from camera recorder?

Comment: @fadden. BTW, strangely, "Show+capture camera" demonstrates the filter effects on preview. But the recorded video has no such filter effects (for example emboss), except the red and green rectangular at the bottom.

Comment: The frame rate is limited by the camera.  The only exception I've seen is on an old Nexus 7 (2012), which gets noticeably slower if you switch to one of the filtered modes.  A lower resolution might yield a higher frame rate.  The absence of filtering on the recorded output is intentional (see the README.md).  You can enable it by modifying the code to select a different shader when rendering to the encoder.

Comment: @fadden, thanks. If we use a regular camera video recording, we can get a higher frame rate, at least 30 fps. So it seems we have potentiality to achieve a higher frame rate, is my understanding right? Just it might need to get into the camera hardware and some APIs to get the raw data directly from hardware camera?

Comment: You should open a new question for that -- we've strayed pretty far from the original.  Tag it with [android] and [android-camera].  Be sure to specify the device and version of Android you're using, as well as what resolution you're capturing at.

Comment: hi fadden, returning back to "fast" effects, do you know the way to attach texture with decoded data to renderscript input allocation and renderscript output allocation to texture for encoder without coping to system memory?